# How to implement Floyd's algorithm finding a shortest path on a 11x11 grid that has rectangle obstacles?

Tags: c++, algorithm, floyd-warshall

I've been trying to figure out how to implement Floyd's algorithm for several days now to find the shortest path in a grid structure as described below. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I would implement something like this? Thanks.

Input:

- Start/End coordinates
- User input must be between 0 to 10 inclusive
- Number of obstacles
- Obstacle coordinates at top-left and bottom-right

Output:

- Path showing all the coordinates that are passed through
- Distance as an int

Restrictions:

- Obstacles cannot overlap
- Start and End cannot be set inside a rectangle obstacle
- Path can include traveling along the edges of the rectangle but never through them
- The path may only go horizontal and vertical, not diagonal
- The distance between two adjacent vertices is 1

I need help generating the conditions for the 121x121 array.

This is what I have so far.

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) { 
   for(j=1;j<=n;j++) { 
         if( edge exists from i to j ) W[i][j] = 1; 
               // distance=1 if nodes are adjacent 
         else if ( edge does not exist from i to j ) W[i][j] = inf; 
              // distance=inf. if nodes do not meet 
         else if ( i = j ) W[i][j] = 0; // distance=0 if i=j 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I need help generating the conditions for the 121x121 array. this is what i got so far.
       
    `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
       for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
       {
          if( edge exists from i to j )
             W[i][j] = 1; // distance=1 if nodes are adjacent
          else if ( edge does not exist from i to j )
             W[i][j] = inf; // distance=inf. if nodes do not meet
          else if ( i = j )
             W[i][j] = 0; // distance=0 if i=j
       }
    }`

Comment: @user1351995 FYI: You can go back and edit your original question on this site. I went ahead and copied your clarification into your question.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm
Just use this pseudo code to implement the algorithm (it shouldn't diferentiate that much from the actual C++ code (it's a fairly simple algorithm). The Wiki link also provides an algorithm for the shortest path reconstruction.
Would you consider implementing a simple Breath First Search because you're dealing with a grid.
Haha this is my first post on this forum :)

Comment: Actually Floyd-Warshall is too slow for this (O(n ^ 3) and n = 121 ^ 2). BFS or A* might be better choice.

Comment: haha you're suggesting A* to a person who's having trouble implementing a simple Floyd Warshall algorithm.

Comment: BFS is easy enough to implement and sufficient to solve the problem. A* is if OP wants to speed up the search between a known src and dest. My solution is just in case the OP wants to find shortest path between some pairs of coordinates. If the same board is used, and there are many queries, then Floyd-Warshall may be a better choice, but it will take a lot of time to finish generating the whole 121x121 array.

Comment: Heyy, I've just answered his question about Floyd Warshall. I know that it's slow. That's why I've suggested BFS in the first place. Also, since he's struggling (or even considering) implementing FW algorithm tells me that he won't be using A star any time soon.